# Improve query time in fast growing DB?

Tags: database, performance, redis

I have a business logic which accesses to multiple tables in multiple DBs
The data in tables are growing fast and data size is huge.
So sql query ( which has some joins in tables ) time is getting slow.

Is there a way to to improve performance?

Answer (score 0):

There are many RDBMS Cache available which will cache the latest results and will act like hot region Cache / L1 cache . I have used GemFireXD in a similar use case and it works great .
Go through below link for more information

[https://blog.pivotal.io/tag/gemfire-xd][1]